# Issue with copying the data from one workbook to another if data does not exist

Tags: excel, vba

We need to copy the data from one work book to another if data is not exists.

```
For example as below.
sheet1 in workbook1
Column1  column2 column 3
abc      ravi     red
def      ramu     blue 
ghi      giri     green

Sheet1 in workbook2
column1 column2  column 3
abc     ravi    black
def     ramu    blue
```

Now we need to compare the column 1 , 2 and 3 in both workbooks and if any of the column data is not matched then data present in sheet 1 of workbook 1 should be appended to sheet 1 in workbook2 without any duplicates

I have tried with the below mentioned code. Not sure where i have made an mistake.

```
Private Sub click()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook


Set y = ActiveWorkbook
Set x = Workbooks.Open("workbook1.xlsx")
Set newbook = Workbooks.Open("workbook2.xls")

ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Name
ActiveWorkbook.Save

b1 = x.Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
a1 = newbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

 For i = 2 To a1
   For j = 2 To b1
     If (newbook.Sheets("ENV").Cells(i, 1).Value <> x.Sheets("ENV").Cells(j, 1).Value And newbook.Sheets("ENV").Cells(i, 2).Value <> x.Sheets("ENV").Cells(j, 2).Value And newbook.Sheets("ENV").Cells(i, 3).Value <> x.Sheets("ENV").Cells(j, 3).Value) Then
     x.Activate
     b = Worksheets("ENV").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
     x1 = x.Sheets("ENV").Cells(j, 1).Value
     y1 = x.Sheets("ENV").Cells(j, 2).Value
     z1 = x.Sheets("ENV").Cells(j, 3).Value
     x.Sheets("ENV").Cells(b + 1, 1).Value = newbook.Sheets("ENV").Cells(i, 1).Value
     x.Sheets("ENV").Cells(b + 1, 2).Value = newbook.Sheets("ENV").Cells(i, 2).Value
     x.Sheets("ENV").Cells(b + 1, 3).Value = newbook.Sheets("ENV").Cells(i, 3).Value

     End If
     Next
     Next
 End Sub
```

Expected result : Get only the data which is not matched
Actual output is : Getting duplicate values

Comment: An approach I would consider would be to add temporary columns in both that concatenates (&) the three values, then performs a VLOOKUP based on each column to determine if the set of values is already present. The columns can be subsequently removed.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @AndyG create a helper column to produce a "unique-ish" lookup field.  Or, use something along these lines to compare the same idea. `if join(application.transpose(sheets("sheet1").range("a1:c1")),"_")=join(application.transpose(sheets("sheet2").range("a1:c1")),"_"))`

Answer (score 0):

You were looping too many times; also, Always assign your variables and don't use things like `a1` which can be confused with a range. You assigned each workbook `Sheet1` to a variable then started using `Sheets("ENV")` which is confusing. Using `And` states that all threes cells have to be changed not just one cell, use `Or`. Your question was not clear which workbook you were trying to update, so I chose `workbook1` as the source workbook and `newbook` as the destination, if I'm wrong just change the variables.

```
Sub TestRngIfNotSameUpdate()

Dim Srcewb As Workbook, Destwb As Workbook
Dim Srcews As Worksheet, Destws As Worksheet
Dim lRowSrcewb As Long

Set Srcewb = Workbooks.Open("workbook1.xlsx")
Set Destwb = Workbooks.Open("workbook2.xls")

Set Srcews = Srcewb.Sheets(ENV)
Set Destws = Destwb.Sheets(ENV)

Destwb.SaveCopyAs Filename:=Destwb.Name
Destwb.Save

lRowSrcews = Srcews.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lRowSrcews
         If Destws.Cells(i, 1).Value <> Srcews.Cells(i, 1).Value _
         Or Destws.Cells(i, 2).Value <> Srcews.Cells(i, 2).Value _
         Or Destws.Cells(i, 3).Value <> Srcews.Cells(i, 3).Value Then

            Destws.Cells(i, 1).Resize(, 3).Value = Srcews.Cells(i, 1).Resize(, 3).Value

         End If
    Next i

End Sub
```